# Restrict inline code in view from having other than model related code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would want to restrict my .cshtml files so that the inline c# code only can be associated to the current model. So I would like to restrict the allowed namespaces or something similar.

The background is that I need the view folder to be edited by the apps users(the admins of the system - not the web visitors).
Some of my customers would want to show the images and some would not.
Therefore I need to be in control of what the can do so they cant do

```
<span>
    title
@{
   MyApp.Database.DeleteAll()
   or
   System.File.Read()
}
```

But I want them to be able to do

```
@foreach(var img in @Model.Images){
      <img src="@img" />
}
```

The users will not have access to the server or to anything else(like webconfig ect). They will edit the .cshtml files through a web interface.

Lets say I have a page where that shows a collection of uploaded images.
Some admins want to show the images as a slider others as a simple ul
This won't have any effect on the rest of the application because everything is loosely connected.

Comment: difficult to understand...

Comment: You can add a generic model to your views, but that still doesn't address the huge security loop hole that you're adding to your app..

Comment: You should definitely rethink your project, what you're planning to do is a very bad idea. There must be safer ways to achieve what you want to do. Perhaps you can elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I would like so each customer can change the view for her application without changing any logic(Some customers wants to display the images and some not). This because every one of my customers has their own view folder and I already have the editor and the different views setup. So everything already works but there is this security issue that I would want to fix.

Comment: You are not going to fix this easily. Creating a security system like this is too time consuming. (You will end up spending more time at security then the actual application). I would suggest to make your own editor and enable adding partial views by special tags.

Comment: Thats already done but at some point in the application the tags must be translated to a cshtml file. Then if c# code has been entered that must be stripped away or just be throw an error upon page load. I could strip c# code but I rather wouldn't its nice to get the flexibility that you get from inlinecode

Comment: And the time it takes to implement the security feature is not an issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible and creates huge security leaks since Razor allows to run any C#-code.

You could instead let them create templates in a different template-engine. There is for instance [Handlebars for C#](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/mustache-sharp#readme) which should allow to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Yeah, thats my problem :). So I guess then I'll just have to go with the templating and stripping of c# inline code. Thanks for the tip but I already have a template system in place. I'll just need to add some stripping